# React Native List goes into endless loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting a certain amount of data through the api. And if this record is less than 6, it goes into continuous loop. How can I solve this problem? I think the problem is with onEndReached and onEndReachedThreshold. Please help me with this. I'm sorry for my bad english.

I am adding sample codes.

*Sample Code:*

```
handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState({
        maxSize: this.state.maxSize + 20
    }, () => {            
        this.loadLead();
    });
};

<List
    style={styles.container}
    data={leadList}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={Divider}
    onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <ListItem
            key={index}
            title={item.name}
            description={'Kayıt Tarihi: ' + Moment(item.createdAt).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}
            accessoryLeft={renderPersonIcon}
            accessoryRight={() => (<Button size='tiny' onPress={ () => Alert.alert('test') }>DETAYLAR</Button>)}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a validation in your onEndReached prop, because every time that you go to the end of your list will execute your handleLoadMore function again, I use onEndReached for an infinite scroll.
An example could be this:

```
onEndReached={()=>{
 if(flag){
 this.handleLoadMore()
}
}}
```